# Java: String method not modifying correctly?

Tags: java

I have been tasked to create an apple program with a certain parameter that the type of apple can only be "Red Delicious", "Golden Delicious", "Gala", and "Granny Smith".

But, for some reason even if I call to the class then set the apple type to "Granny Smith" I still get an "This is an invalid type of apple". Also, it won't modify the default type name from "Gala". Maybe my `if` statement is wrong?

*Here's the Apple class:*

```
public class Apple {

private String type;
private double weight;
private double price;

//Default apple values (Constructors)
public Apple ()
{
    this.type = "Gala";
    this.weight = 0.5;
    this.price = 0.89;
}
//Accessors
public String getType()
{
    return this.type;
}
public double getWeight()
{
    return this.weight;
}
public double getPrice()
{
    return this.price;
}
//Mutators
public void setType (String aType)
{
    if (!aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Red Delicious") || !aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Golden Delicious") || !aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Gala") || !aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Granny Smith"))
    {
        System.out.println ("That is an invalid type of apple");
        return;
    }
    this.type = aType;
}
public void setWeight (double aWeight)
{
    if (aWeight < 0 || aWeight > 2)
    {
        System.out.println("That is an invalid weight");
        return;
    }
    this.weight = aWeight;
}
public void setPrice (double aPrice)
{
    if (aPrice < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("That is an invalid price");
        return;
    }
    this.price = aPrice;
}
//Methods
public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + type + " Weight " + weight + " Price " + price;
}
public boolean equals (Apple aApple)
{
    return this.type.equalsIgnoreCase (aApple.getType()) && this.weight == aApple.getWeight() && this.price == aApple.getPrice();
}
```

*Here's the apple tester code that calls upon my Apple class:*

```
System.out.println("Setting the new apple's values to the following valid values: Granny Smith, 0.75, 0.99\nPrinting the new apple's values");
Apple grannySmith = new Apple();
grannySmith.setType("Granny Smith");
grannySmith.setWeight (0.75);
grannySmith.setPrice (0.99);
System.out.println(grannySmith+ "\n");
```

In the output, it says it is an invalid type of apple for some reason and also it sets the "Name: Gala" which Gala is default, and it doesn't change the name to "Granny Smith".

> Creating another apple
>
> Setting the new apple's values to the following valid values: Granny Smith, 0.75, 0.99
>
> Printing the new apple's values
>
> That is an invalid type of apple
>
> Name: Gala Weight 0.75 Price 0.99

I don't know why it says it is an invalid type of apple and why it prints the name as the default apple type instead of what I set it to. Maybe my mutator if statement is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using AND (`&&`) rather than OR (`||`). You want to print the error message if all of the conditions are `true`, rather than if just one of them is `true`.

```
public void setType (String aType)
{
    if (!aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Red Delicious") 
        && !aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Golden Delicious") 
        && !aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Gala") 
        && !aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Granny Smith"))
    {
        System.out.println ("That is an invalid type of apple");
        return;
    }
    this.type = aType;
}
```

Consider the case where your type is `"Gala"`. That is not equal to `"Red Delicious"` and so your original statement would see that as invalid, and fail on the very first check.

You can simplify the boolean condition to be more readable by changing it to:

```
!(aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Red Delicious") 
        || aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Golden Delicious") 
        || aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Gala") 
        || aType.equalsIgnoreCase("Granny Smith"))
```

Or, better yet:

```
List<String> apples = Arrays.asList({ "Red Delicious", "Golden Delicious", "Gala", "Granny Smith" });

if (apples.contains(aType)) { ... }
```